# Django filter object and get specified attribute

Tags: django

Is there any (efficient, or built in) way that allows me get a list of an object field when using the Objects.filter?

for example if I have a model

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    point   = Models.ForeignKey(Point)
    target = Models.ForeignKey(Pages)
```

Can I do a query that will return

```
[<Point>, <Point>, <Point>]
```

such that those points are the ones who are following, say, target_id = 1. Or in other words, the points that occure in

```
Follow.objects.filter(target_id=1)
```

I realize that I can do the query, and then do some python code, looping trough the result to get the fields that I want, but is there a way I can do it in Django?

Comment: You might want to try this..
`Point.objects.filter(follow__target_id=1)`

Comment: That returned `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Follow' into field.`

Comment: Did you use `Follow` or `follow` as field name in filter ?